# Very slow SELECT query in MySQL in a 10 Million rows table (single table)

Tags: mysql, performance, select, optimization

I have a performance issue with my query.
Here is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `file_info` (
  `FILE_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `START_TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `END_TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `FILE_SIZE` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LOG_SERVER_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PHASE` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `APPLICATION` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TYPE` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `FULLPATH` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `COMPRESSED` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CLOSED` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ARCHIVED_PATH` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `FILE_TYPE` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`LOG_SERVER_NAME`,`FULLPATH`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_file_info` (`LOG_SERVER_NAME`,`FULLPATH`,`APPLICATION`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `IDX_STARTTIME` (`START_TIME`),
  KEY `IDX_ENDTIME` (`END_TIME`),
  KEY `IDX_PHASE` (`PHASE`),
  KEY `IDX_APLICATION` (`APPLICATION`),
  KEY `IDX_LOGSERVERNAME` (`LOG_SERVER_NAME`),
  KEY `IDX_FULLPATH` (`FULLPATH`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM FILE_INFO 
WHERE PHASE ='DEV' 
AND APPLICATION ='SIALT'
AND ((START_TIME <'2014-11-11 08:17:00' AND END_TIME >'2014-11-11 08:17:00') 
   OR (START_TIME <'2014-11-11 08:22:00' AND END_TIME >'2014-11-11 08:22:00') 
   OR (START_TIME >'2014-11-11 08:17:00' AND END_TIME <'2014-11-11 08:22:00'))
```

The query tasks a looooot of time. Sometimes more than 30 sec.

I have put indexes on the fields I am filtering.
I am using MyISAM because I understood that it is better if the DB has no foreign keys.

So I am looking for new ideas to improve my query. It is barely not usable today.

Adding a autoincrement key would help ? Even though I don't filter by ID ?
Changing from MyISAM to InnoDB ?

**EDIT**

Explain gives

```
id  1
select_type SIMPLE
table   FILE_INFO
type    ref
possible_keys   IDX_STARTTIME,IDX_ENDTIME,IDX_PHASE,IDX_APLICATION
key IDX_APLICATION
key_len 257
ref const
rows    756718
Extra   Using index condition; Using where
```

I will try the other suggestions and update my post.

Thanks for the hints.

Romain.

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN SELECT....` say?

Comment: What happens if you drop all those individual indexes and instead have one compound index on  (PHASE,APPLICATION,START_TIME) or (PHASE,APPLICATION,START_TIME,END_TIME)?

Comment: It seems you have defined the times columns to `timestamp`, and you're querying as if they were `DATETIME`. Leaving the timing aside, are you really getting results in these selected time ranges??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions.

I changed the indexes to include all my where clauses in the primary key. It was not enough.

I saw that the partitioning based on datetime was not used correctly.
So what I have done is to create a new date field (based on start_time). And the partitionning works great with the date (without time).

Here is the final query:

```
SELECT * FROM FILE_INFO 
WHERE PHASE ='PDT' AND APPLICATION ='SIALT' 
AND FILE_DATE = '2014-12-10'
AND ((START_TIME <'2014-12-10 08:17:00' AND END_TIME >'2014-12-10 08:17:00') 
OR (START_TIME <'2014-12-10 17:22:00' AND END_TIME >'2014-12-10 17:22:00') 
OR (START_TIME >'2014-12-10 08:17:00' AND END_TIME <'2014-12-10 17:22:00'))
```

I guess the indexing on start_time was just not working correctly for some reason. I could explain the very bad performances.

Comment: Do you remember how long the query took after you fixed that?

Answer (score 1):

You should use RANGE BASED partitioning, create the partitions based on date, may be on a month or a week, that will boost the performance.

Comment: good point, with this idea i think its also possible to leave the table as it is and build another based on time range eg weeks or month (like ur idea) and only store the ids in there - what do u think?

Comment: I remember, I used to work on a database, the size of the database was 1.9TB and it was on mysql ..The heaviest tables were managed with partitioning but I would recommend you to create a back up of the table first..Create 2 replicas, on first replica, apply the weekly partitioning and on the second replica, apply the monthly partitioning..check out the execution time of both the tables and compare them :).

Answer (score 1):

You should reduce the size of the VARCHAR columns to the smallest size that you can. While VARCHAR saves room on data page storage by only using what's needed, index entries still use the maximum. For latin1 VARCHAR(255) columns, that's 255 bytes for each row. **You have a primary key size of 512 bytes.**

After you improve the size of your columns, a multi-column index on the following three columns would be ideal for read speed `(phase, application, start_time)`. We don't include end_time because your compound index is only good up to the first range. Between phase and application, put whichever has higher cardinality first (more uniqueness). Keep the index on end_time, as MySQL may be able to use the index merge optimization.

Then, to help MySQL out and let it perform range scans turn your `OR` into a `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT * FROM FILE_INFO 
WHERE PHASE ='DEV' 
AND APPLICATION ='SIALT'
AND (START_TIME <'2014-11-11 08:17:00' AND END_TIME >'2014-11-11 08:17:00')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM FILE_INFO 
WHERE PHASE ='DEV' 
AND APPLICATION ='SIALT'
AND (START_TIME <'2014-11-11 08:22:00' AND END_TIME >'2014-11-11 08:22:00')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM FILE_INFO 
WHERE PHASE ='DEV' 
AND APPLICATION ='SIALT'
AND (START_TIME >'2014-11-11 08:17:00' AND END_TIME <'2014-11-11 08:22:00')
```

There is also a chance, depending on your data, that you may need to force MySQL to use the multi-column index (instead of the index on end_time).

Such large indexes need lots of RAM (the entire index needs to be in memory at all times to be fast), and proper MySQL configuration.

Comment: I did reduce the size of the varchar. Thanks for the hint. Not ssure if it improved the perf though.